# Ford Ka - blowing hot air after new alternator was fitted

Tags: ford, alternator, air, ka

Hi I have had a new alternator fitted today, I have had the car back and drove it and turned on the cold air in my car and its just blowing out hot air, I never had this issue before the new alternator was fitted.

Any ideas? I have the mechanic coming back out tomorrow to take a look but I'd like to know if it could be down to the new alternator or not.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'd also check that the serpentine belt, which drives both the alternator and the A/C compressor, is properly installed.

Comment: Please do not type in all capital letters. It's seen as shouting, and is impolite here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet the problem is they either knocked the A/C clutch wire loose or forgot to hook it back up during the Alternator install. It would not be unreasonable for the wiring to be close, considering both the alt and A/C are up front on the engine and very near each other.